# Создание списка из массива?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте уважаемые !

Как вывести из массива я уже понял , а вот как вывести из массива в список - вот это у меня не получается , подскажите как это делается !

Вот то что я пробовал и то что получилось :

```js
var friends = [" Алексей", " Вячеслав", " Григорий", " Настя", " Павел"];
var i = 0;

while (i <= friends.length - 1){

document.write(friends[i]);

i = i + 1;

}
```

Как вместо того что бы просто вывести текст из массива на страницу , обрамить тегом параграфа или списком ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обход массива в js ([ссылка](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration))

Функция `forEach(item, i, arr)`:

`item` – значение элемента массива.

`i` – его номер.

`arr` – массив, который перебирается.

Списком:

```js
var friends = [" Алексей", " Вячеслав", " Григорий", " Настя", " Павел"];
html = '<ul>';
friends.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
  html += '<li>'+item+'</li>';
});
html += '</ul>'

document.write(html);
```

Или параграфом:

```js
var friends = [" Алексей", " Вячеслав", " Григорий", " Настя", " Павел"];
friends.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
  document.write('<p>'+item+'</p>');
});
```

Comment: я плюсик не могу поставить ! почему ?

Comment: а для чего используется item,i,arr внутри скобок ?

Comment: Обновил ответ. Добавил описание функции forEach